# Finding Maximum, Minimum and Average values using KStreams Stateful or stateless transformations?

Tags: java, lambda, stream, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I wanted to know which **stateful** or **stateless** operations I have to perform to find the **maximum**, **minimum** and **average** values for the field age on a `Kstream` record.

User have two field `int age` `String name.`
The key is `String name`

---

```
KStream<String, user> stream = builder.stream("Topic1");
```

Comment: `aggregation()`: maybe it's worth to read the docs and check out the examples here: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Comment: aggregation as a stateful transformation for calculating max and min is perfect but for the average value calculation it's supposed to be just stateless transformations.

Comment: How is the average computation stateless?

Comment: that's my question.

Comment: It's no possible to do a stateless average...